# Get raw HTML code of polymer elements

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Let me explain the situation:

There is a paper-input inside a div(#content). Now I want to get html code inside the div#content for that I had used `$("#content").html()`.

But `$("#content").html()` is giving me the code injected by polymer.

Example:

The expected output of `$("#content").html()` is:

```
         <paper-input label="text input"></paper-input>
```

But is is giving me the below result:

```
     <paper-input label="text input" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" class="x-scope paper-input-0">
       <paper-input-container class="style-scope paper-input x-scope paper-input-container-0">
        ....
        <template is="dom-if" class="style-scope paper-input-container"></template>
        ....
        ...
     </paper-input>
```

Is there any iron element to get raw html code.

Answer (score 0):

The expected output of `$("#content").html()` is correct as those nodes created by polymer now belong to the DOM.

If for some reason you need the raw html of the element that was created without changing the original element you can always clone it, clear it's children and remove atributes that were created by polymer

```
var cln = $('#content paper-input').clone().html('')[0];
cln.removeAttribute('tabindex');
cln.removeAttribute('class');
cln.removeAttribute('aria-disabled');
console.log(cln.outerHTML);
```